# Understanding Future and Completer in Flutter.... How to use the controller to load a new url from a webview

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, webview

I cannot load a new URL in flutter Webview... I have issues using `then` and `Future` in flutter `Webview` Controller...

In a flutter `Webview`, I would like to load the `initialUrl`, then programmatically retrieve some information from that web page... All works well so far... But then I want the `Webview` to automatically load another webpage... but I am not sure how to use the `controller`  and the `Completer` to do that

Snippet:

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
    _controller.complete(webViewController);
    },
  onPageFinished: (String url) async{
    if (url == 'https://flutter.dev') {
      // *** I retrieve some data, then I want to navigate ***
      _controller!.loadUrl('https://google.com'); // *** ERROR HERE ***
    }
  },
)
```

I tried using the `controller` directly,

```
_controller!.loadUrl('https://google.com');
```

it works if I don't use a `Completer` and instead I just assign the `controller`

```
_controller = webViewController;
```

but does not seem a recommended option:

I found other examples using a `FutureBuilder`, but I am not trying to build anything

Here is the full code, in case useful:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  
  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
        onPageFinished: (String url) async{
          if (url == 'https://flutter.dev') {
            // *** I retrieve some data, then I want to navigate ***
            _controller!.loadUrl('https://google.com'); // *** ERROR HERE ***
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the subject of how to use completer in that case!

**Replace** `onPageFinished` **callback with the following snippet and read the comments carefully**

```
  onPageFinished: (String url) async{
              // add the missing '/' at the end of the url since the url string is 'https://flutter.dev/' 
              // NOT 'https://flutter.dev'
              if (url == 'https://flutter.dev/') {
                // *** I retrieve some data, then I want to navigate ***
                final wvController = await _controller.future;
                await wvController.loadUrl('https://google.com');
                // ***
                // No More ERROR
                // HERE ***)
              }
            },
```

Comment: Thanks @Saed Nabil ... This is what I was looking for... Please would you have any recommendation if I should use controller completer (as in the documentation of Webview) or should I use just a controller as in the answer of Onur below?? Actually, it works fine without the completer and my other animations (not shown here) do not lag as when I use a completer

Comment: @Canada2000 Thank you , My recommendation is to stick to the documentation for now as it is more null safe and if you interested please open another question with your animation issue may be we can more help you, peace!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use iterators and controllers. No need to mess with the index. After calling the moveNext() function, the URL in the iterator is updated. You can also open a new URL with the loadUrl() function of the controller.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class SamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SamplePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SamplePage> createState() => _SamplePageState();
}

class _SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {
  late WebViewController _webViewController;
  Iterable<String> urlStrings = [
    'https://www.google.com/',
    'https://www.yahoo.com/',
    'https://www.bing.com/',
    'https://flutter.dev/',
    'https://altavista.com/'
  ];
  late Iterator<String> urlIterator;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // init url iterator.
    urlIterator = urlStrings.iterator;
    urlIterator.moveNext();

    // Enable virtual display.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) => setState(() => _webViewController = controller),
        initialUrl: urlIterator.current,
        onPageFinished: (url) {
          urlIterator.moveNext();
          _webViewController.loadUrl(urlIterator.current);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Onur... This works well... but it seems using the "Cmpleter" is the recommended way (I am not sure though)